# React TransitionLeave in if/else return

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css-transitions

I'm building a React component which returns one of two components depending on a `prop`.

```
if (!this.prop.myProp) {
  return (<Compontent1 />)
} else {
  return (<Compontent2 />)
}
```

When the `prop` is changed I'd like the element which is being removed to  transition away, while the appearing element should transition in.

The `transitionEnter` on the new element works fine. This was accomplished by wrapping the component in `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` and adding the appropriate classes with transition rules.

The transition on the element leaving does not work. It disappears instantly and the `transitionEnter` on the entering element begins. Here's my full code:

```
if (!user) {
    header = (
      <ReactCSSTransitionGroup key="login"
                               component="div"
                               className="app-header--login"
                               transitionName="login"
                               transitionEnter={false}
                               transitionEnterTimeout={0}
                               transitionLeave={true}
                               transitionLeaveTimeout={600}>
        <button className="button button--login"
                onClick={this._handleLogin.bind(this)}>
          Join
        </button>
      </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
    )
  } else {
    header = (
      <ReactCSSTransitionGroup key="form"
                               component="div"
                               className="app-header--form"
                               transitionName="form"
                               transitionEnterTimeout={0}
                               transitionLeaveTimeout={0}
                               transitionAppear={true}
                               transitionAppearTimeout={600}>
        <Form user={user} />
      </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
    )
}

return ({header});
```

The transition classes are intentionally simple at the moment, to make sure the transition is working.

```
.login-leave {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.6s ease-in;
}

.login-leave.login-leave-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.6s ease-in;
}
```

Am I implementing `transitionLeave` incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

"Am I implementing transitionLeave incorrectly?" I don't think so.

But you have misplaced the `key` attribute.

It should be in the **children**, not in `ReactCSSTransitionGroup`. That's the reason why the transitionLeave is not working, React doesn't know which children has entered or left.

```
  return (<div>
      <ReactCSSTransitionGroup 
                               component="div"
                               className="app-header--login"
                               transitionName="login"
                               transitionEnter={false}
                               transitionEnterTimeout={0}
                               transitionLeave={true}
                               transitionLeaveTimeout={600}>
        {!user ? <button key="login" className="button button--login"
                onClick={this._handleLogin.bind(this)}>
          Join
        </button> : null}
      </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
      <ReactCSSTransitionGroup 
                               component="div"
                               className="app-header--form"
                               transitionName="form"
                               transitionEnterTimeout={0}
                               transitionLeaveTimeout={0}
                               transitionAppear={true}
                               transitionAppearTimeout={600}>
        {user ? <Form key="form" user={user} /> : null}
      </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
    </div>)
```

Comment: Removing the `key` from the `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` and moving it to the child elements causes no transition to occur, even on the entering element.

Comment: hm that's probably because you are unmountaing the whole ReactCSSTransitionGroup(didn't see that). I guess that you should add both elements(Form & button) in the same ReactCSSTransitionGroup. About the key, you should add it in the children as you can see in the docs, https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html

Comment: So instead of having the `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` in each conditional, wrap the output of the conditional in the `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` component?

Comment: yep, I edited the answer. You can use a ternary operator for that.

Comment: Not sure that will make it possible to get the effect I need. when the page loads there should be a bar at the top of the page. it should move off the top of the page on leave, the new element should move onto the page from the top on enter.

Comment: I edited it again, using two ReactCSSTransitionGroup and just changing the children based on the user value, that way you won't need to unmount the whole transition group and you'll be able to keep the transitionLeave

Comment: Results in an `onlyChild` error. I eventually found a solution that mostly works, but still some timing issues. I'll post it as a solution below.